# Issue configure Charles proxy on Catalina

Tags: charles-proxy, macos-catalina

When starting *Charles* after getting a new MacBook Pro with Catalina, I get the following message

> Charles cannot configure your proxy settings while it is on a read-only volume

Answer (score 10):

None on the above solutions worked for me. Both gives error as "Charles Proxy Settings" is not a directory

Instead of the file give the ownership & permission to the entire resources folder

```
sudo chown -R root "/Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Resources"
sudo chmod -R u+s "/Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Resources"
```

Answer (score 8):

Found solution to this. After running this it worked fine. Previously, "Charles Proxy Settings" was in the `MacOS` directory and was recently moved to the `Resources` directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
SETTINGS_BIN="/Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Resources/Charles Proxy Settings"
chown root "${SETTINGS_BIN}"
chmod u+s "${SETTINGS_BIN}"
```

Comment: Surprisingly I don't see "Charles Proxy Settings" inside Resources folder.

Answer (score -1):

Good to me! Thanks
My Shell,as below

```
#!/bin/bash -il
# coding=UTF-8
cd ~
SETTINGS_BIN="/Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Resources/Charles Proxy Settings" 
sudo chown root "${SETTINGS_BIN}" 
sudo chmod u+s "${SETTINGS_BIN}"
```